# Problem solving Move uploaded file error 8 on PHP 7.2 - UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION

Tags: php, file, php-7.2

I am posting one file from a html5 form and PHP an want to movie into a certain directory.
Move_uploaded_file throws error 8 meaning unspecifically UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION.

The Ubuntu Server is running PHP 7.2, **no Suhosin extension**.
I already checked the apache error.log file but did not find any entry concerning the operation at all.

Before I changed to move_uploaded_file, I was dealing with the copy command COPY(...) which also threw an error, so I learned that move_uploaded_file is the method of choice.

Results from my checks so far:

```
print_r($_FILES);
Array ( [customFile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Logo 011.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpJVODjF ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 210813 ) ) )
```

The file ought to be moved to: 
/home/csitestore/images/25

Permissions for this directory are 777 so full access for everyone to make sure that this is not the problem:
`drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data      www-data      4096 Okt  4 09:15 25`

PHP.ini says:

```
post_max_size = 99M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 99M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_execution_time = 90
max_input_time = 90
memory_limit = 512M
```

But the file I was trying to upload is only about 210kB so the restrictions are not taking any effect I think.

How do I get a more specific description of the error "UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION"? Or how can I proceed solving it?

My form tag from the html file:

```html
<form action="send_data.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
```

Code from send_data.php for uploading and moving file:

```php
if(!is_dir("/home/csitestore/images/25")){
  if (!@mkdir("/home/csitestore/images/25")){
      $error = error_get_last();
      echo $error['message'];
  } else {
    chmod("/home/csitestore/images/25", 0777);
  }
}

$path = "/home/csitestore/images/25/test.jpg";
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['customFile']['tmp_name'][0], $path)) --> [0] because I normally use this inside a loop but I am trying with just one file
  {
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "Error: ".$errors['type']; = 8 => UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
  }
```

Don't really know how to proceed now.

Comment: I don’t think your error here is actually UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION. According to the manual, that one occurs when _“a PHP extension stopped the file upload”_ - but that would occur during the upload phase already, and would be reflected in the `error` entry in $_FILES. But according to your own debug output, you got `[error] => Array ( [0] => 0 )` there - so _no_ error during the upload phase. You might have gotten a numeric error code 8 later - but that has nothing to do with UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION then.

Comment: That's what is really striking me. After move_uploaded_file I am catching the error by typing echo "Error: ".$errors['type'];  And I really don't get where the error comes from. The latest action is moving the file. The catched error is numeric 8. So I relate this to move_uploaded_file.

Comment: Mayme I figured out what's going on.
Checking the filename from $_FILES['customFile']['tmp_name'][0] i get "/tmp/phpJQlYHu" . So the uploaded file should show up in the ubuntu tmp directory right? But it does not . I commented move_uploaded_file out so that the uploaded file should be resting in the temp dir, but there is nothing.
Another fact coming to my mind right now is that I wrote another upload script that is also no longer working using the "copy" command. I did apt upgrade a week ago. Maybe that's it?
Rights of the tmp dir: ```drwxrwxrwt  10 root root       4096 Okt  6 12:09 tmp```

Comment: Okay solved. The problem was a misconfiguration in samba.